# Versioning Theorem numbers with amsthm

Tags: amsthm

I would like to have different versions of the same theorem or definition.  So version 0 of definition 1 would be called "Definition 1.0" and version 1 would be called "Definition 1.1".  The file below returns the error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].` on compilation.  What am I doing wrong?

I copied the relevant code from [here](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/chngcntr/chngcntr.sty) and changed some of the details:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{dfn}[section]

\newcounter{dfnv}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{thedfnv}{\@nameuse{thedfn}.\arabic{dfnv}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{dfn}[dfnv]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{dfn}% Should display as Definition 1.0
  Version 0 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn}% Should display as Definition 1.1
  Version 1 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfn}

\begin{dfn}% Should display as Definition 2.0
  Version 0 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn}% Should display as Definition 2.1
  Version 1 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I fixed it, I just apparently can't use the same name, `dfn`, for the theorem type and the counter.  I'm not putting this as an answer because I don't know why it's a problem.

Comment: Circular definition, probably

Answer (score 1):

You of course cannot intermix versioned definitions. I suggest two environments: `dfn` will step the main number, whereas `dfn*` only steps the version number.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcounter{dfnmain}[section]
\newtheorem{dfninner}{Definition}[dfnmain]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thedfninner}{%
  \arabic{dfnmain}.\@arabic{\numexpr\value{dfninner}-1\relax}%
}
\makeatother
\newenvironment{dfn}
 {\stepcounter{dfnmain}\dfninner}
 {\enddfninner}
\newenvironment{dfn*}
 {\dfninner}
 {\enddfninner}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}

\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn*}
  Version 1 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn*}

\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn*}
  Version 1 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn*}

\section{Second section}

\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn*}
  Version 1 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn*}

\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}

\begin{dfn*}
  Version 1 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the numbers to also refer to the section number, add `\arabic{section}.` in the definition of `\thedfninner`.