# Starting theorem version numbering at 1.0 instead of 1.1

Tags: amsthm

How I make the numbering in the following file start at `1.0` instead of `1.1`?  `setcounter{dfnv}{-1}` doesn't do anything.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{dfnq}[section]
\newcounter{dfnv}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{dfnv}{dfnq}
\let\thedfnvsaved\thedfnv
\renewcommand{\thedfnv}{\thedfnq.\thedfnvsaved}
\makeatother

%% \makeatletter
%% \@namedef{thedfnv}{\@nameuse{thedfnq}.\arabic{dfnv}}
%% \makeatother

\newtheorem{dfn}[dfnv]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}


\stepcounter{dfnq}
% Should display as Definition 1.0
% Actually displays as Definition 1.1
\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 1.1
% Actually displays as Definition 1.2
\begin{dfn}
  Version 1 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfnq}

% Should display as Definition 2.0
% Actually displays as Definition 2.1
\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 2.1
% Actually displays as Definition 2.2
\begin{dfn}
  Version 1 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfnq}

\end{document}
```

Full disclosure:  this is a continuation of [my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371731/versioning-theorem-numbers-with-amsthm).

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to subtract 1 to the value of your counter when you use it (in `\thedfnv`). Here it is done using a temporary counter.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{dfnq}[section]
\newcounter{dfnv}[dfnq]
\newcounter{tmpcnt}

\renewcommand{\thedfnv}{
\setcounter{tmpcnt}{\value{dfnv}}\addtocounter{tmpcnt}{-1}\thedfnq.\thetmpcnt}


\newtheorem{dfn}[dfnv]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}


\stepcounter{dfnq}
% Should display as Definition 1.0
% Actually displays as Definition 1.1
\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 1.1
% Actually displays as Definition 1.2
\begin{dfn}
  Version 1 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfnq}

% Should display as Definition 2.0
% Actually displays as Definition 2.1
\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 2.1
% Actually displays as Definition 2.2
\begin{dfn}
  Version 1 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfnq}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: a way to get labels to work correctly

- decouple `dfnv` form `dfnq` (not strictly necessary but we'll handle the
  dependency manually)
- initialize `dfnv` to `-1`
- define a command `\nextdef` that you will call instead of `\stepcounter{dfnq}` :

  `\newcommand{\nextdef}{\stepcounter{dfnq}\setcounter{dfnv}{-1}}`
- redefine `\thedfnv` the good old way:

  `\renewcommand{\thedfnv}{\thedfnq.\arabic{dfnv}}`

And voilà, should work correctly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{dfnq}[section]
\newcounter{dfnv}
\setcounter{dfnv}{-1}

\renewcommand{\thedfnv}{\thedfnq.\arabic{dfnv}}

\def\nextdef{\stepcounter{dfnq}\setcounter{dfnv}{-1}}

\newtheorem{dfn}[dfnv]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}


\stepcounter{dfnq}
% Should display as Definition 1.0
% Actually displays as Definition 1.1
\begin{dfn}\label{defa}
  Version 0 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 1.1
% Actually displays as Definition 1.2
\begin{dfn}\label{defb}
  Version 1 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}
\nextdef

% Should display as Definition 2.0
% Actually displays as Definition 2.1
\begin{dfn}\label{defc}
  Version 0 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 2.1
% Actually displays as Definition 2.2
\begin{dfn}\label{defd}
  Version 1 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}
\nextdef

\ref{defa}

\ref{defb}

\ref{defc}

\ref{defd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do I get `\label` to work?  Right now it still gives the old numbers `1.1`, `1.2`, etc.

Comment: OK, TeX black magic going on here, I don't know how `\label` works precisely but things get messed up on the way. I'm adding a workaround.

Comment: OK my proposition is basically MadyYuvi's answer with a lot more text all around...

Answer (score 0):

Put `\setcounter{dfnv}{\numexpr\value{dfnv}-1\relax}` after every occurence of `\stepcounter{dfnq}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{dfnq}[section]
\newcounter{dfnv}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{dfnv}{dfnq}
\let\thedfnvsaved\thedfnv
\renewcommand{\thedfnv}{\thedfnq.\thedfnvsaved}
\makeatother

%% \makeatletter
%% \@namedef{thedfnv}{\@nameuse{thedfnq}.\arabic{dfnv}}
%% \makeatother

\newtheorem{dfn}[dfnv]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{First section}


\stepcounter{dfnq}
\setcounter{dfnv}{\numexpr\value{dfnv}-1\relax}
% Should display as Definition 1.0
% Actually displays as Definition 1.1
\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 1.1
% Actually displays as Definition 1.2
\begin{dfn}
  Version 1 of the definition of foo.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfnq}
\setcounter{dfnv}{\numexpr\value{dfnv}-1\relax}
% Should display as Definition 2.0
% Actually displays as Definition 2.1
\begin{dfn}
  Version 0 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}

% Should display as Definition 2.1
% Actually displays as Definition 2.2
\begin{dfn}
  Version 1 of the definition of bar.
\end{dfn}
\stepcounter{dfnq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

\setcounter{dfnq}{-1} and follows...

Comment: This doesn't do the job, the `dfnq` counter has the appropriate values, it is the way the `dfnv` counter increments is reset when the `dfnq` counter increments that is the problem as detailed in existing answers.